# Yii2 Basic Globale variable and function

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

With Yii2 basic is it possible to create variables and function that I can use in all controllers and views; If it possible can help on how I try create it on : config/params.php

```
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'dafult-Img' => 'upload/user/'.Yii::$app->user->getId().'/',
];
```

but when I use it on controller

```
$model->userimage= Yii::$app()->params['dafult-Img'];
```

I get error

```
Undefined variable: app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yii2 you should use `$app` and not $app()

```
 Yii::$app->params['dafult-Img'];
```

could be you need  a

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUU; YOU MAKE MY DAY

Comment: I'm always wondering why people don't check doc's after moving from Yii to Yii2 :)